# Finding Customer Order Frequency

Tags: sql-server

I need a query which gives me the result for the customers same production orders within 10 days. Because of production management, manufacturer doesn't like customers which orders same product several times in a short period of time (for example 10 day is shord for me)

Here is the sample order table code.

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE(Customer VARCHAR(50), Product VARCHAR(50), OrderDate DATE)

INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES
('A Company','w102', '2016-10-10'),('A Company','w102', '2016-10-12'),('A Company','w102', '2016-10-24'),
('B Company','w302', '2016-11-11'),('B Company','w302', '2016-11-15'),('B Company','w302', '2016-11-17'),
('C Company','w404', '2016-11-17'),('C Company','w404', '2016-11-24'),('C Company','w405', '2016-11-24')

select * from @Orders ORDER BY Customer, OrderDate
```

So how can I get list of customers orders same thing within 10 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `EXISTS` to check for another order with the same customer and product within 10 days of the original order:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @Orders AS o
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    @Orders AS o2
            WHERE   o2.Customer = o.Customer
            AND     o2.Product = o.Product
            AND     o2.OrderDate > o.OrderDate
            AND     o2.OrderDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 10, o.OrderDate)
        );
```

Which gives:

```
Customer    Product     OrderDate
---------------------------------------
A Company   w102        2016-10-10
B Company   w302        2016-11-11
B Company   w302        2016-11-15
C Company   w404        2016-11-17
```

This will only return the details of the first of the two orders, if you need details of the next order (such as date), then you could use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  o.Customer,
        o.Product,
        FirstOrderDate = o.OrderDate,
        NextOrderDate = o2.OrderDate
FROM    @Orders AS o
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 o2.OrderDate
            FROM    @Orders AS o2
            WHERE   o2.Customer = o.Customer
            AND     o2.Product = o.Product
            AND     o2.OrderDate > o.OrderDate
            AND     o2.OrderDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 10, o.OrderDate)
            ORDER BY o2.OrderDate
        ) AS o2;
```

Which gives:

```
Customer    Product FirstOrderDate  NextOrderDate
------------------------------------------------
A Company   w102    2016-10-10      2016-10-12
B Company   w302    2016-11-11      2016-11-15
B Company   w302    2016-11-15      2016-11-17
C Company   w404    2016-11-17      2016-11-24
```

A third version, available only in SQL Server 2012 and higher would be to use `LEAD()` or `LAG()`:

```
SELECT  o.Customer,
        o.Product,
        o.FirstOrderDate,
        o.NextOrderDate
FROM    (   SELECT  o.Customer,
                    o.Product,
                    FirstOrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                    NextOrderDate = LEAD(o2.OrderDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, Product ORDER BY o.OrderDate)
            FROM    @Orders AS o
            WHERE   o2.Customer = o.Customer
        ) AS o
WHERE   o.NextOrderDate > o.FirstOrderDate
AND     o.NextOrderDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 10, o.FirstOrderDate);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a very satisfying answer.